# Render text over image in several lines

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uigraphicsimagerenderer

I am working on a Swift project where I need to add a rotated watermark text to an existing UIImage. I have implemented a function that uses UIGraphicsImageRenderer to draw the image and apply the watermark in the centre. However, I need to make it look like this:

My goal

[image: what I need]

My result
[image: result]

I've only figured out how to rotate in by 45 degrees and position in centre. No luck in implementing the presented higher example.

```
    private func addWatermark(_ text: String, to image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: image.size)
        let watermarkedImage = renderer.image { context in
            image.draw(at: .zero)
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .font: UIFont(name: "Inter", size: 50 * 3)!,
                .foregroundColor: UIColor(Color(red: 0.58, green: 0.64, blue: 0.72)).withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            ]
            let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)
            
            // Calculate the center position
            let centerX = (image.size.width - textSize.width) / 2
            let centerY = (image.size.height - textSize.height) / 2
            
            // Calculate the center point of the text
            let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: centerX + textSize.width / 2, y: centerY + textSize.height / 2)
            
            // Rotate the context around the center point by 45 degrees
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: centerPoint.x, y: centerPoint.y)
            context.cgContext.rotate(by: CGFloat.pi / 4) // 45 degrees in radians
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: -centerPoint.x, y: -centerPoint.y)
            
            let textRect = CGRect(
                x: centerX,
                y: centerY,
                width: textSize.width,
                height: textSize.height
            )
            
            text.draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: attributes)
        }
        return watermarkedImage
    }
```

Comment: You posted 2 example images. Which one is your goal, the one in English, or the one in.. Ukrainian?

Comment: And how does the code you posted fail to meet your requirements?

Comment: Updated the code for clearer understanding

Comment: It only renders text at the centre of the image, I need to render the text all over it

Comment: Well there's your problem. You need to write code that renders the text repeatedly, in multiple lines. You're not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only draws the watermark string once. Your sample image draws the watermark string over and over, and it rotates it more like -π/10.

I did some tinkering and came up with an extension on UIImage, based on your code, that adds a watermark over and over, and tilted closer to your sample image. That code looks like this:

```
extension UIImage {
    func addWatermark(_ text: String, color: UIColor = .red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)) -> UIImage {
        
        let fontSize = 120.0
        let stringArray =  [String](repeating: text, count: 100)
        let longString = stringArray.joined(separator: "     ")
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        let watermarkedImage = renderer.image { context in
            draw(at: .zero)
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize),
                .foregroundColor: color
            ]
            let textSize = longString.size(withAttributes: attributes)
            
            // Calculate the center position
            let centerX = (size.width - textSize.width) / 2
            let centerY = (size.height - textSize.height) / 2
            
            // Calculate the center point of the text
            let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: centerX + textSize.width / 2, y: centerY + textSize.height / 2)
            
            let renderedTextSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)
            print(renderedTextSize)
            
            // Rotate the context around the center point by 45 degrees
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: centerPoint.x, y: centerPoint.y)
            context.cgContext.rotate(by: -CGFloat.pi / 10) // 45 degrees in radians
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: -centerPoint.x, y: -centerPoint.y)
            
            let textRect = CGRect(
                x: -size.width * 0.4,
                y: -fontSize,
                width: size.width * 2,
                height: size.height * 1.2
            )
            
            /*
             //The path below lets you see where the text box lands in your image's frame. Un-comment this code to see the rotated bounds of the textRect
            let path = UIBezierPath.init(rect: textRect)
            path.lineWidth = 5
            UIColor.white.setStroke()
            path.stroke()
             */
            longString.draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: attributes)
        }
        return watermarkedImage
    }
}
```

And when I load an image that's a screenshot from my phone, call `addWatermark("Add watermark")` on it, and install that into an image view that takes up most of the screen, it looks like the below.

The code from my test app's view controller is simply:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Screenshot")?.addWatermark("Add watermark", color: UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.2, blue: 0.8, alpha: 0.5))
    }
```

[image]

### Edit:

I did some further tweaking and got the output to look even closer to your sample. (I reduced the rotation angle to π/12, I changed the text color to an opaque, low saturation gray/blue, I increased the line spacing, and I switched the screenshot to text on a white background like your sample image.)

The results look like this:[image]

The new code looks like this:

```
extension UIImage {
    func addWatermark(_ text: String, 
                      color: UIColor = UIColor(red: 153/255.0, green: 163/255.0, blue: 183/255.0, alpha: 1.0)) -> UIImage {
        
        let fontSize = 120.0
        let stringArray =  [String](repeating: text, count: 100)
        let longString = stringArray.joined(separator: "    ")
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .light)
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0.75 * (font.lineHeight)
        let watermarkedImage = renderer.image { context in
            draw(at: .zero)
            let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
                .font: font,
                .foregroundColor: color,
                    .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle
            ]
            let textSize = longString.size(withAttributes: attributes)
            
            // Calculate the center position
            let centerX = (size.width - textSize.width) / 2
            let centerY = (size.height - textSize.height) / 2
            
            // Calculate the center point of the text
            let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: centerX + textSize.width / 2, y: centerY + textSize.height / 2)
            
            let renderedTextSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes)
            print(renderedTextSize)
            
            // Rotate the context around the center point by 45 degrees
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: centerPoint.x, y: centerPoint.y)
            context.cgContext.rotate(by: -CGFloat.pi / 12)
            context.cgContext.translateBy(x: -centerPoint.x, y: -centerPoint.y)
            
            let textRect = CGRect(
                x: -size.width * 0.4,
                y: -fontSize,
                width: size.width * 2,
                height: size.height * 1.2
            )
            
            /*
             //The path below lets you see where the text box lands in your image's frame. Un-comment this code to see the rotated bounds of the textRect
            let path = UIBezierPath.init(rect: textRect)
            path.lineWidth = 5
            UIColor.white.setStroke()
            path.stroke()
             */
            longString.draw(in: textRect, withAttributes: attributes)
        }
        return watermarkedImage
    }
}
```

Comment: My sample code is full of "magic numbers" that I just came up with experimentally to make the text look about the same size as your sample image, and cover a full-screen image completely. You will need to adapt it to your needs (and make it more generalized to handle different length watermark strings and different image sizes.)

Comment: See the edits to my answer. I tweaked the code to look more like your sample image.

Comment: (From looking at your sample, it appears the "watermark" is fully opaque. I would recommend using an alpha of 0.5 to 0.75, since if it's fully opaque it makes the underlying image hard to see.)